# Postgres query with JSONField on array

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-jsonfield

I am new to Postgres, and try to build a SQL query that can retrieve a Key/Value dictionary pair in an array `[]` from table `table_b`  and use it in the `WHERE` clause on finding matching `tag_name` and `tag_value` returning the `object_uuid`

The original `tags` on `table_b` were stored as `JSONField()` in Django -> Postgres and not sure how that would work in array on extracting each one out.

Question: How do we build a SQL query can traverse each `name` and `value` in `table_b.tags` and then use it to match it on `table_a`?

**table_a**

| tag_name | tag_value | object_uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foobar | coffee | aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee |
| hello | world | 3dd98cb6-978c-44b0-92fd-403032a7cb1f |
| key_one |  | 81bba637-4156-42b2-a2c0-ae5dd23ed695 |

**table_b**

| id | object_uuid | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444 |  |
| 4 | 99999999-8888-7777-6666-555555555555 |  |
| 271 |  | [{"name": "foobar", "value": "coffee"}, {"name": "hello", "value": "world"}] |

I think I come with this

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    object_uuid,
    name,
    value
FROM table_b b,
     jsonb_to_recordset(b.tags) AS (name TEXT, value TEXT)
```

| id | object_uuid | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 271 |  | foobar | coffee |
| 271 |  | hello | world |

Answer (score 0):

You can join using the `@>` operator after building an array with the tagname and value:

```
select b.id, b.object_uuid, a.tag_name, a.tag_value
from table_b b
  join table_a a on b.tags @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('name', a.tag_name, 'value', a.tag_value));
```

This assumes that `table_b.tags` is a `jsonb` column (which it really should be). If it's not, you need to cast it `b.tags::jsonb`